# Javascript comparsion "or" logic is lost upon me

Tags: javascript

I'm  learning js on codecademy and I did an exercise called rock paper scissors but I'm having trouble understanding one thing:

```
if ((userChoice != "rock") && (userChoice != "paper") && (userChoice != "scissors"))
    {
        console.log("Sorry but you didn't enter a valid option. Use all lowercase letters and no punctuation. But the computer will automatically assign you an object so you can still play");
        userChoice = Math.random();
            if (userChoice < 0.34) {
            userChoice = "rock";
            } else if(userChoice <= 0.67) {
                    userChoice = "paper";
                    } else {
                    userChoice = "scissors";
        } console.log("Human: " + userChoice);
    }
else
    {
        console.log("You chose: " + userChoice);
    };
```

so I got it to work but why doesn't

```
if (userChoice != "rock" || "paper" || "scissors")
```

work? so I kinda get the the && version because it's like if this is true then do this and if this is true then do this and if this is true then do this but I don't see why the or version doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the syntax used for the && operator perhaps you should be doing:

```
if ((userchoice != "string") || (userchoice != "other string"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (userChoice != "rock" || "paper" || "scissors")`

Break this down into the expressions:

- `userChoice != "rock"`  (will be true or false)
- `"paper"` (true)
- `"scissors"` (true)

Regardless of `userChoice`, the if will always be true due to the [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) of the strings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please do not ask this type of question as you can look it up on google in 2 seconds. But I will explain it to you.

First off `if (userChoice != "rock" || "paper" || "scissors")` 
should be 
`if (userChoice != "rock" || userChoice != "paper" || userChoice != "scissors")`

comparative AND "&&" and comparative OR "||" operations are different.

this && that -only evaluates true if both are true

this || that -evaluate true if one or both is true

Also please read about truthiness from blurd's answer.